# Installed VirtualBox from EXE, Requires MSI for Change/Repair

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-installer

I downloaded and installed VirtualBox from an EXE file, but when I go to Change/Repair, it requires an MSI installer.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007) stated in [your previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/275570/windows-admin-privileges-required-after-install/275578#275578):

> The VirtualBox .EXE installer is a wrapper for an MSI

You can [view one of the WiX files used to build the MSI](http://www.virtualbox.org/browser/trunk/src/VBox/Installer/win/VirtualBox.wxs) in VirtualBox's source code repository. The EXE package you download installs the MSI behind the scenes.